Why non-member and templated operator is syntactically correct but doesn't work in C++
I see that the following is syntactically correct:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T> bool operator<= (const T& left, const T& right)
{
  cout<<"overloaded"<<endl;
  return left<=right;
}


int main()
{
    cout<<(10<=5)<<endl;
    return 0;
}

But it seems that it is never called.

It is called just fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/b9r3Phcv7

I specified how I call the operator

Why ... instead of something that could be compiled and tested that demonstrates the issue?

Side note, do not do this in production code (you also overload operators for built-in
and standard library types). It may lead to surprising results (like a lot of code no longer working correctly)

Yes, I just would like to know what is happening here

In general, you can only overload operators when you own at least one of the operand types. Hence you can't change the behavior of operators for built-in types.

"When an operator appears in an expression, and at least one of its operands has a class type or an enumeration type, then overload resolution is used to determine the user-defined function to be called . . ."

"Yes, I just would like to know what is happening here". It's simple: 10<=5 calls the default built-in operator of a bool checking whether 10 is less or equal to 5, it does not call your new operator. As HolyBlackCat said, you can't change the behavior of operators for build ins. You could at most wrap them in a struct or template class and use that new type with a different behavior (see Yksisarvinen's example).

You can not overload the predefined operators for predefined types

Side note: when that function does get called, the return left<=right; will call the same function, recursively, forever (or until the program crashes).

Just because something is syntactically correct does not mean it does what you think it does (or should do).

why C++ operator overloading requires "having at least one parameter of class type"? and Do built-in operators participate in overload resolution?

For overloaded operators to be called, at least one operand needs to have class or enumeration type:

If no operand of an operator in an expression has a type that is a class or an enumeration, the operator is assumed to be a built-in operator and interpreted according to [expr.compound].

- [over.match.oper] p1
Your operator<= is valid and would be called if one of the operands was say, of class type, but in 10<=5, both operands are int, i.e. of fundamental type.
Also note that return left<=right; would result in infinite recursion (in almost all cases) since it would call the overloaded <= operator again.
Furthermore, it's highly unusual to overload operators in a way that they would be called for standard library types (or attempt to do that for fundamental types). See also Is it allowed to overload operator+ for a standard library type and a built-in type?. You should stick to overloading operators only for your own types, e.g. by making them a hidden friend or member functions, or constraining them properly.

Following the comment of Yksisarvinen below the question, it would't result in infinite recursion.

@Discipulos because Yksisarvinen's function ends with return false;. Your function ends with return left<=right;, which does result in infinite recursion: https://godbolt.org/z/1jGY9h9hE
